# How to grep other text except that already in script

Tags: bash, grep

I'm making a filter email script on bash, the only problem I have is I want to `grep -c` a text that except `Hotmail, Outlook, Gmail, Etc` and make it as `Other` the example script is provided as here ,

```
echo "Hotmail : `grep -c "@hotmail" $inputFile`"
echo "Outlook : `grep -c "@outlook" $inputFile`"
echo "Yahoo : `grep -c "@yahoo" $inputFile`"
echo "Gmail : `grep -c "@gmail $inputFile`"
```

i want all other email like @sbc , @mail.ru or anything email that not listed above counted as Other , Thank you

Comment: Not clear, could you please add samples of input and expected output in your post and let us know then?

Comment: its start by inputin the email list  `read -p "[!] Enter Your Maillist :  " inputFile` , and i want all other email like @sbc , @mail.ru or anything email that not listed above counted as Other , example `echo "Other : `grep -c ______ $inputFile`"`

Comment: the blank is want i want to know how

Comment: Sorry but still not clear, could you please add simple samples of input and expected output in your post and let us know then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
echo "Other : `egrep -vc '@(hotmail|outlook|yahoo|gmail)' $inputFile`"
```

The -v flag causes grep to only grep those lines whetre the pattern does not appear.
egrep enables for the (...|...|...) alternatives.